# Singular, plural, and ... summarial?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Whenever someone asks me if I got a haircut, I always reply "actually, I got all of them cut;" or if someone mentions going for a haircut, I ask "oh really, which one?" It's a dumb old dad joke I know.

But it got me thinking ... I realize that there aren't many cases where a noun form can mean either a *singular* instance, or *all* of it, but 'hair' happens to be just such a case.

- `Singular`: I plucked a (single) *hair*.
- `Plural`: I lost two *hairs*.
- **`???`**: I got (all) my *hair* cut.

I was wondering whether there is a specific grammatical term for this "third" amount-specifier?

Comment: The word *all* in this case is an adjective, not a noun. It means *the whole amount*. On its own, it can be used whether there is a single instance of something in a set or more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has actually already been discussed on [EL&U!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9951/is-hair-singular-or-plural)

To summerise:

> This seems to be one of those plural issues where a different plural is used when referring to the large uncountable group. "I found 3 gray hairs this morning" is proper but so is "I washed my hair this morning".
>
> In the second case, your entire head covered with individuals hairs is treated as a single object or group which is why it is referred to in a singular form.
>
> The word hair in some cases is a **collective noun**, and in other cases is not a collective noun.
>
> As reported from the NOAD, the meaning of the word is:
>
> Any of the fine threadlike strands growing from the skin of humans, mammals, and some other animals.
>   Such strands collectively, especially those growing on a person's head.
>   In most of the phrases, the word used is hair; in some cases is hairs (to split hairs).